# Connection to local SQL Server database works on emulator but fails on real device

Tags: android, sql, sql-server, database-connection

I am trying to connect to an SQL Server database that is currently hosted on my local machine. I am using the following code to connect:

```
public class DBConnect {

    private static volatile DBConnect INSTANCE = null;
    String URL = "";
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    private DBConnect() {

    }

    public static DBConnect getInstance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (DBConnect.class) {
                INSTANCE = new DBConnect();
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public void setConnection(String DBName, String UserName, String Password) {
        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            URL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.0.81:1433;instanceName=SQLEXPRESS;DatabaseName=" + DBName + ";integratedSecurity=true;user=" + UserName + ";password=" + Password;
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This works on my Genymotion emulator since I also executed a select and seen the results being displayed.

I am using the JTDS driver to do this

However when I try with a real device that is on the same Wi-Fi network it doesn't work, I get a connection error.

Any ideas why I am getting this?

This is my error log:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.81 (port 1433) after 90000ms
07-18 08:29:09.465  27413-27514/ordermanager.sentosa.ro.ordermanager W/System.err﹕ at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:410)
07-18 08:29:09.466  27413-27514/ordermanager.sentosa.ro.ordermanager W/System.err﹕ at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:187)
07-18 08:29:09.466  27413-27514/ordermanager.sentosa.ro.ordermanager W/System.err﹕ at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:175)
07-18 08:29:09.467  27413-27514/ordermanager.sentosa.ro.ordermanager W/System.err﹕ at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:140)
07-18 08:29:09.467  27413-27514/ordermanager.sentosa.ro.ordermanager W/System.err﹕ at ordermanager.sentosa.ro.ordermanager.utils.DBConnect.setConnection(DBConnect.java:39)
```

Comment: Is your firewall blocking the incoming connection?

Comment: I didn't get prompted to allow any connection so i have no idea...

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on an emulator on a machine which is not also the database server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible solutions to your problem that i can see:

1. your are using a Genymotion emulator which is probably working on a different network
2. check if your SQL Server database is accessible in online mode by setting this:

   `ALTER DATABASE database-name SET ONLINE`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might get solved by simply TURNING OFF the WINDOWS FIREWALL. Firewall will prevent your real device from establishing connection with your local MS SQL server.
By doing so it worked fine for me.

BUT since turning off firewall is not a good idea, configure the Windows Firewall for Database engine access, click this link and follow the steps.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-windows-firewall-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-ver15