# Android app runs only on emulator but not on device

Tags: android, mysql, json, localhost, android-networking

I have created an application that fetches contents from an online MySQL Database.
I have used JSON Parser for that. My app works fine on the emulator but on my mobile device it is no able to fetch the contents.

This is my code till now:
AllPapersActivity.java

```
package com.papershare.bhanu;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AllPapersActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> papersList;

    // url to get all papers list
    private static String url_all_papers = "http://kidessential.esy.es/android_connect_paper/get_all_papers.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_paperS = "papers";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";

    // papers JSONArray
    JSONArray papers = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_papers);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        papersList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading papers in Background Thread
        new LoadAllpapers().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single paper
        // launching Edit paper Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        WebViewer.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

    }

    // Response from Edit paper Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received 
            // means user edited/deleted paper
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all paper by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllpapers extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllPapersActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading papers. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All papers from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_papers, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All papers: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // papers found
                    // Getting Array of papers
                    papers = json.getJSONArray(TAG_paperS);

                    // looping through All papers
                    for (int i = 0; i < papers.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = papers.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String descrip = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, descrip);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        papersList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no papers found
                    // Launch Add New paper Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            NewPapersActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all papers
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllPapersActivity.this, papersList,
                            R.layout.list_item, 
                            new String[] { TAG_PID,TAG_NAME, TAG_DESCRIPTION},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.description});
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

and this is JSONParser.java

```
package com.papershare.bhanu;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method.equals("POST")){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method.equals("GET")){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

As you can see I am hosting my php files in my hostinger account and I also have my MySQL database also created.
Here is the logcat when the app is run in USB Debugging mode.

```
03-22 16:42:23.268: D/dalvikvm(531): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
03-22 16:42:23.508: I/dalvikvm(531): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 8...
03-22 16:42:24.228: I/dalvikvm(531): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-22 16:42:24.238: I/dalvikvm(531): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-22 16:42:24.648: I/dalvikvm(531): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-22 16:42:24.698: D/dalvikvm(531): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 64K, 2% free 12613K/12867K, paused 261ms
03-22 16:42:24.718: I/dalvikvm(531): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-22 16:42:24.738: I/dalvikvm-heap(531): Grow heap (frag case) to 15.890MB for 3686416-byte allocation
03-22 16:42:24.858: D/dalvikvm(531): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 2% free 16212K/16519K, paused 4ms+14ms
03-22 16:42:25.058: D/dalvikvm(531): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 2% free 16212K/16519K, paused 31ms
03-22 16:42:25.118: I/dalvikvm-heap(531): Grow heap (frag case) to 22.140MB for 6554896-byte allocation
03-22 16:42:25.148: I/dalvikvm(531): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-22 16:42:25.199: I/dalvikvm(531): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-22 16:42:25.237: D/dalvikvm(531): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 2% free 22613K/22983K, paused 5ms+5ms
03-22 16:42:25.618: D/(531): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x17c018, tid 531
03-22 16:42:25.728: I/dalvikvm(531): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-22 16:42:25.738: I/dalvikvm(531): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-22 16:42:26.328: I/dalvikvm(531): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-22 16:42:26.338: I/dalvikvm(531): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-22 16:58:22.478: I/dalvikvm(531): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-22 16:58:22.518: I/dalvikvm(531): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-22 16:58:22.958: I/dalvikvm(531): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-22 16:58:23.117: I/dalvikvm(531): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-22 16:58:24.167: I/dalvikvm(531): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-22 16:58:24.178: I/dalvikvm(531): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-22 17:01:32.008: W/System.err(531): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://10.0.2.2 refused
03-22 17:01:32.008: W/System.err(531):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
03-22 17:01:32.008: W/System.err(531):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
03-22 17:01:32.008: W/System.err(531):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
03-22 17:01:32.008: W/System.err(531):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
03-22 17:01:32.008: W/System.err(531):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
03-22 17:01:32.008: W/System.err(531):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
03-22 17:01:32.008: W/System.err(531):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
03-22 17:01:32.038: W/System.err(531):  at com.papershare.bhanu.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:62)
03-22 17:01:32.048: W/System.err(531):  at com.papershare.bhanu.AllPapersActivity$LoadAllpapers.doInBackground(AllPapersActivity.java:128)
03-22 17:01:32.048: W/System.err(531):  at com.papershare.bhanu.AllPapersActivity$LoadAllpapers.doInBackground(AllPapersActivity.java:1)
03-22 17:01:32.048: W/System.err(531):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
03-22 17:01:32.048: W/System.err(531):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-22 17:01:32.058: W/System.err(531):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-22 17:01:32.058: W/System.err(531):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-22 17:01:32.058: W/System.err(531):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-22 17:01:32.058: W/System.err(531):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-22 17:01:32.068: W/System.err(531): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 80): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
03-22 17:01:32.068: W/System.err(531):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
03-22 17:01:32.078: W/System.err(531):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
03-22 17:01:32.078: W/System.err(531):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
03-22 17:01:32.078: W/System.err(531):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
03-22 17:01:32.078: W/System.err(531):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
03-22 17:01:32.078: W/System.err(531):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
03-22 17:01:32.088: W/System.err(531):  ... 15 more
03-22 17:01:32.088: W/System.err(531): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
03-22 17:01:32.097: W/System.err(531):  at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
03-22 17:01:32.097: W/System.err(531):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
03-22 17:01:32.097: W/System.err(531):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
03-22 17:01:32.097: W/System.err(531):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
03-22 17:01:32.108: W/System.err(531):  ... 20 more
03-22 17:01:32.108: E/Buffer Error(531): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 17:01:32.108: E/JSON Parser(531): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
03-22 17:01:32.117: W/dalvikvm(531): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
03-22 17:01:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(531): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-22 17:01:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(531): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-22 17:01:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
03-22 17:01:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
03-22 17:01:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
03-22 17:01:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
03-22 17:01:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-22 17:01:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-22 17:01:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-22 17:01:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-22 17:01:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(531): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 17:01:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at com.papershare.bhanu.AllPapersActivity$LoadAllpapers.doInBackground(AllPapersActivity.java:131)
03-22 17:01:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at com.papershare.bhanu.AllPapersActivity$LoadAllpapers.doInBackground(AllPapersActivity.java:1)
03-22 17:01:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
03-22 17:01:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-22 17:01:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  ... 4 more
03-22 17:01:32.808: I/dalvikvm(531): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-22 17:01:32.838: I/dalvikvm(531): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-22 17:01:34.098: I/dalvikvm(531): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-22 17:01:34.118: I/dalvikvm(531): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-22 17:01:35.828: E/WindowManager(531): Activity com.papershare.bhanu.AllPapersActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41fe6a18 that was originally added here
03-22 17:01:35.828: E/WindowManager(531): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.papershare.bhanu.AllPapersActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41fe6a18 that was originally added here
03-22 17:01:35.828: E/WindowManager(531):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:344)
03-22 17:01:35.828: E/WindowManager(531):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
03-22 17:01:35.828: E/WindowManager(531):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
03-22 17:01:35.828: E/WindowManager(531):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
03-22 17:01:35.828: E/WindowManager(531):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
03-22 17:01:35.828: E/WindowManager(531):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
03-22 17:01:35.828: E/WindowManager(531):   at com.papershare.bhanu.AllPapersActivity$LoadAllpapers.onPreExecute(AllPapersActivity.java:118)
03-22 17:01:35.828: E/WindowManager(531):   at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
03-22 17:01:35.828: E/WindowManager(531):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
03-22 17:01:35.828: E/WindowManager(531):   at com.papershare.bhanu.AllPapersActivity.onCreate(AllPapersActivity.java:58)
03-22 17:01:35.828: E/WindowManager(531):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-22 17:01:35.828: E/WindowManager(531):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-22 17:01:35.828: E/WindowManager(531):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
03-22 17:01:35.828: E/WindowManager(531):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
03-22 17:01:35.828: E/WindowManager(531):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-22 17:01:35.828: E/WindowManager(531):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
03-22 17:01:35.828: E/WindowManager(531):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-22 17:01:35.828: E/WindowManager(531):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-22 17:01:35.828: E/WindowManager(531):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-22 17:01:35.828: E/WindowManager(531):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 17:01:35.828: E/WindowManager(531):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-22 17:01:35.828: E/WindowManager(531):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-22 17:01:35.828: E/WindowManager(531):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-22 17:01:35.828: E/WindowManager(531):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-22 17:06:32.377: I/Process(531): Sending signal. PID: 531 SIG: 9
```

Please tell where in my code this 10.0.2.2 is creating problem while running this app on the mobile device

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61428658/11684415
It has something to do with WINDOWS FIREWALL, check this answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to access a `localhost` web service on your local network. You should know that such a web service can only be accessed by an emulator on a computer which is presumably on the same local network as the server. A *real* device cannot access a web service on a local network.

To test your app on a real device, you need to expose your web service through a public URL, which can be accessed on a public network. Do this and it will work.

Comment: Nonsense. Using the local ip address of the sever will do.

Comment: @greenapps: the last time you got into an argument with me on a similar question, the OP marked my answer correct and you ended up with egg on your face.

Comment: @ZygoteInit : I am using a hosting my php files on the web but I have somewhere missed to change the code while moving to online from my WAMP Server. I have added the codes also.

Comment: @greenapps: I am trying to put my application online, so I am giving my server's address.

Comment: @user3312672: so you mean that even after hosting it on a server with a public URL, you are not able to access the web service from a phone ?

Comment: @ZygoteInit: exactly. The application works fine on emulator, that means I have established the connections properly but in my mobile device it can't load the content from my online MySQL database

Comment: @user3312672: in your Android app, have you changed all URLs from localhost to public URLs ? Or are you still using 10.0.2.2 somewhere ?

Comment: @ZygoteInit: I have changed all the URLs to the public URL, as you can see in the code that I have included just now.

Comment: @user3312672: try uninstalling the old APK completely and then re-run the new Android code from your IDE ... hopefully it should work.

Comment: @ZygoteInit: nope, it just stops after showing the progress dialog for a long time. I think that there is some problem with the JSON code, as it uses DefaultHTTPClient method

Comment: @user3312672: are you getting any new errors or unusual messages in your logcat ? Also check whether you are able to open the public URLs in your desktop PC's browser ... :)

Comment: @ZygoteInit: Same errors even now and the URL is working in my browser.

Comment: @user3312672: if you are still getting an `HttpHostConnectException`, then the URL you are trying to access is not on a public network ... you need to investigate this

Comment: @ZygoteInit: I changed the URL in JSON's get method from "url" to the actual public url and it worked, The parameter String url is still holding that old localhost url value(don't know how). So I explicitly chaged it like this    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://kidessential.esy.es/android_connect_paper/get_all_papers.php");

Answer (score 0):

10.0.2.2 can only be used if your app runs on an emulator. For a real device change to the local ip address of the server in your wlan.

Comment: I have moved my php files to a web hosting account and modified the url of the file also. I have included my code also in the edit, please tell me where I am missing to change the code so it can be hosted online.